# Rails radio buttons not working properly and related issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created three models, "Survey", "Question", and "Answer". Survey has_many Questions which has_many Answers (and they all belong to the model above them).

This is the form I want to display the questions and submit user input with:

```
<%= form_for(:quiz_responses, url: quiz_responses_path) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :name, value: @survey.name %>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<ul> 
<%= f.hidden_field :question, value: question.content %>
<%= f.label question.content %>

<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :answers, value: answer.content %>

<%= f.label answer.content %>
<%= f.radio_button(:user_answer, answer.content) %>

<% end %>
```

There's a few problems with it:

1. If I create more than one question, for example 2 questions, I'll get 8 radio buttons, 4 for each question (intended result). However, I can only select one out of the 8 radio boxes (instead of one out of the 4 radio boxes for each question), and only one `:user_answer` value is submitted. How do I fix this?
2. This is most likely related to #1, but `<%= f.hidden_field :answers, value: answer.content %>` only produces one value when I submit the form (the last answer value). I want it to submit all the answer values (so if I have 2 questions, I'll get a params hash containing 8 answer values instead of 1). A similar problem arises with `<%= f.hidden_field :question, value: question.content %>`

Comment: You should watch these two links to learn about nested fields: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1, http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2. it is exactly your case I think.

Comment: I should have clarified. I used nested fields in forms where I create the survey. The form I posted above is after the survey is created, where I'm showing the survey for user input. I don't know if nested forms is the best way to do that.

Comment: If you have saved your survey then why would you need a form_for to display it? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here, but without nested forms you most likely getting duplicated ids for the fields or something else. I still would advise you to watch those railscasts. That website is very useful for a beginner.

Comment: I did watch them. There's two form_for's because they perform different actions: one form is for me to create the quiz, add questions and answers. the second form is to both show the quiz questions and answers AND get user input (ie picking which answer they believe to be correct). I think I know what to do now though.

Comment: Well, look into your server logs to see how many questions/answers do you really save into database, and query your database to confirm. You can also try to create a separate form for each your user_answer. Unfortunately, your question does not provide enough info about what could be wrong, as it depends on what was saved and how you models look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1. is because all 8 radio buttons have the name `user_answer`. You will need to make sure each group has a different name, for instance something that includes the question ID. Maybe `"user_answer[#{q.id}]"` so you get a hash on the back end.

For 2., I expect your browser is actually sending all 8 values (you could check with your Inspector's Network tab), but Rails is only giving you one because of how it treats params. Again, you should make sure that each hidden field has a unique name (combining the question ID and answer ID this time).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I managed to fix it. However, is there a way to order each answer and question starting from 0 instead? For example, since I have a bunch of answers stored in my database, doing <%= f.hidden_field "answer[#{answer.id}]", value: answer.content %> will give me an answer hash with elements starting from whatever the first answer.id happened to be. I managed to make them start from 0 by changing it to answer[#{answer_counter}] instead and incrementing answer_counter after I run that line but it seems sort of... not right.

Comment: Well you can do whatever you want, because you're just creating `<input>` elements, and even in 2016 it's all just HTML and "CGI". But certain param names enable Rails "magic", like `foo[bar]`, so it's nice to use those when you can. (No need for `bar` to be an id though.) Also, if incrementing a count bugs you, instead of `each` try `each_with_index`.